# Skip SSL certificate verification in Spring Rest Template - Spring Boot 3.x.x

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, apache-httpclient-5.x

How can I skip SSL certificate verification in Spring Rest Template with Spring Boot 3? I am finding lots of solutions online and on Stack Overflow which are compatible with Spring Boot 2.x.x but don't work with Spring Boot 3.x.x

```java
TrustStrategy acceptingTrustStrategy = (X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) -> true;
 
SSLContext sslContext = org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts.custom()
        .loadTrustMaterial(null, acceptingTrustStrategy)
        .build();
 
SSLConnectionSocketFactory csf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);
 
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
        .setSSLSocketFactory(csf)
        .build();
 
HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory =
        new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
 
requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);
 
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
```

This code gives compilation error in Spring Boot 3.

Comment: did anyone figure this out?  I have tried multiple suggestions but none work in Spring Boot 3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like this to create the HTTP client:

```java
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.HttpClients;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManagerBuilder;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactoryBuilder;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.ssl.TrustAllStrategy;
import org.apache.hc.core5.ssl.SSLContexts;

[...]

private CloseableHttpClient getHttpClient()
      throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
    return HttpClients.custom()
        .setConnectionManager(
            PoolingHttpClientConnectionManagerBuilder.create()
                .setSSLSocketFactory(
                    SSLConnectionSocketFactoryBuilder.create()
                        .setSslContext(
                            SSLContexts.custom()
                                .loadTrustMaterial(null, TrustAllStrategy.INSTANCE)
                                .build())
                        .setHostnameVerifier((s, sslSession) -> true)
                        .build())
                .build())
        .build();
  }

[...]
```

Obviously you shouldn't use this in production as it's completely insecure.